# Azure DevOps: se Azure Keyvault Secrets in Bash Script

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I've exposed a few secrets in the pipeline from a keyvault by adding a variable group and linking the key vault secrets. According to the logs the secrets are downloaded. However, i'm having issues accessing these secret. From what i understand these variables are exposed as normal variables and using the echo command they're set to environment variables.

If if output the echo to a textfile i can see the secrets, so that seems to work. However, the curl commands fails, it seems that it's not using those secrets and i have no clue why?

**Edit: solved, sometimes you just need a break**

Added the screenshot if someone is ever wondering how to use keyvault secrets in azure devops

[image]

Comment: Looks like this issue is resolved. Can you post an answer so that this post can be found easily to help more people?

Comment: @bruun Thanks for sharing your solution here,  would you please convert your solution into an answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 0):

To make this post considered resolved and easier to discover, i move your solution to answer.

***Question:***

> For how to use keyvault secrets in azure devops?

***Solution:***

[image]